# Split Array for svg polyline JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

How can i split in JavaScript an array of data

```
{x:30, y:45, x:36, y:49}
```

into the form

```
[30, 45, 36, 49]
```

?

I need this form in order to pass the coordinates to SVG polyline. I found a method called `Array.prototype.map` but i can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Your input data is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object repeats keys and this is not allowed in javascript. The map function is for arrays not for objects.

In case you had an object with keys x,y,z you could convert it to array using `Object.values`

```js
const obj = {x:30, y:45, z:36};

//outputs: [30, 45, 36]
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

But if you wanted to construct a polyline you would have an array like the following:

```
[{x:30, y:45},{x:36, y:49}]
```

And then you would have the map method. And you could do something like this:

```js
const coords = [{x:30, y:45},{x:36, y:49}];

const polyline = coords.map((c)=> c.x + "," + c.y).join(' ');


// outputs: 30,45 36,49
console.log(polyline);
```

Comment: i did it using a for loop, but now is better, thank you.